# Get the index of a button (while pressing) which is in an array

Tags: python, arrays, user-interface, button, tkinter

I have saved some buttons in an array:

```
buttons = []
labels.append(tk.Label(fr2, text="", pady=15))
labels.append(tk.Label(fr3, text="", pady=15))
```

Later I access to a table of a database and loop this table with "for in" so I get all rows from the table in my program. For each row I activate a button with grid.

```
i = 0
    if len(records) > 0:
        for row in records:
            print("current_date", ", target date")
            print(current_date, row[2])

            date = current_date - row[2]

            labels[i] = tk.Label(fr2, text=row[1], pady=15)
            labels[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='we')
            labels[i+1] = tk.Label(fr3, text=date, pady=15)
            labels[i+1].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='we')
            buttons[i] = tk.Button(fr4, text="Restart", command=restart, pady=13)
            buttons[i].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='we')
            buttons[i+1] = tk.Button(fr5, text="Delete", command=delete, pady=13)
            buttons[i+1].grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='we')

            i = i + 1
```

How can I get the index of the button I put on when the program is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass argument to the function you use as command.

example:

```
def myButttonCommand(index):

   print("this is the "+index+"th' button")

buttons = []

for i in range (0,10):

   buttons[i] = tk.Button(command=myButtonCommand(i))
```

Comment: The code you posted will not work. The command will be called immediately when the button is created.

Comment: I can guarantee this won't work. `myButtonCommand(i)` will _immediately_ call that function.

Comment: maybe the first comment is correct the thing i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the point of your answer but you can use this piece of code. Below, you have an array of buttons in Tkinter and you access the index of one of those buttons when it's clicked:

```
import tkinter as tk

def printIndex(i):
     print("Index: " + str(i))

buttons = []

for i in range (5):
   buttons.append(tk.Button(command=lambda i=i:printIndex(i)))
   buttons[i].grid(row=i, column=0)
```